# Javascript: Change data-target="#" depending on the value of nput type="text"

Tags: javascript, html

Scenario: If user inserted 1 and click Search the data-target should be nophase if it's 2 then it should be withphase.


 I'm trying to figure it on javascript, can someone give me a hand?


HTML Code:

```
<label for="inputPRNO" class="sr-only">PRNO</label>
<input id="act1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PRNO">

<button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nophase" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> Search </button>

              <div class="collapse" id="nophase">
                <div class="card card-body">
                  No phase.
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="collapse" id="withphase">
                <div class="card card-body">
                  With phase.
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: When you say "inserting" 1, do you mean typing 1 into a text field?

Comment: I don't see any `nput type="text"` in your code. But you'd want to add an [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event listener to that element, inspect its value and set the attribute accordingly.

Comment: @JLowther Correct.

Comment: @Amadan My fault did not place the code for that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it doesn't appear as there is any text field in the above code, but I imagine you intended to include it, so say you have `<input type="text" id="inserter">`, simply add an event listener to the submit button, that checks the value of the input, and change the data attribute accordingly

```js
ok.addEventListener("click", e=> {
  if(inserter.value.toString() == "1") {
    ok.setAttribute("data-target", "#nophase");
  } else if(inserter.value.toString() == "2") {
    ok.setAttribute("data-target", "#withphase");
  }
  console.log(ok.getAttribute("data-target"));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inserter">
<button id="ok" data-target="#nowith">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

let assume we have these HTML code:

```js
function setSource(){
  let inputValue=document.getElementById('inputText');
  let btn=document.getElementById('btn1');
  
  btn.setAttribute('data-target','#nophase');
  if(inputValue.value==2){
    btn.setAttribute('data-target','#phase');
  }
  
  let phasex=btn.getAttribute('data-target');
  
  console.log(phasex);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Input text</label><input id="inputText" />


  <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nophase" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" onClick="setSource()"> Search</button>
</div>
 <div class="collapse" id="nophase">
  <div class="card card-body">
  No phase.
  </div>
  </div>

<div class="collapse" id="withphase">
<div class="card card-body">
With phase.
</div>
</div>
```